# Can't find "Online accounts " in system settings panel

Tags: system-settings, online-accounts

I can't find "online accounts " in system settings.I have Unbuntu12.04 LTs.

Answer (score 0):

Online accounts were introduced in Gnome 3.6 or 3.8 I believe, Ubuntu 12.04 uses Gnome 3.4